# Angular 5 how to keep component's activity going on in background (Ionic 3)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-services, angular5

I found when Angular component is loaded on parent HTML file, it will lose its activity as a user navigates to other parts of parent HTML file.

For instance, inside angular component, I have a CSS3 animation going on triggered by a start animation button on angular component.

When I navigate to other part of its parent html file, angular component's CSS3 animation will automatically stop and I will have to manually trigger it again.

Is there any way to keep that animation going in Angular component when the component is hidden / in background?

It looks like component automatically goes back to its default state when it's hidden / in background.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you consider cache ?

Comment: Hi AmrAyoub, how can I use cache in Ionic 3 / Angular 5? I would love to try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I maybe misunderstood your needs, but have you seen this ? 
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry. I'm talking about component's activity inside an app... not the whole app. When component is not in display within an app, I want it to still do what it was doing in background.

Comment: Any other opinion would be still appreciated!

Comment: What is the goal ? Can you provide an example about what you want to achieve ?

Comment: for example, I have a media progress bar made with CSS3 animation inside a component. The media playback will not stop even when a component is set to hidden from display. It will be playing file in background... thus CSS3 animation should be going on with it. However, right now, CSS3 animations will stop as soon as component is not in display mode... while media playback would be still playing. Any idea on how to keep this CSS3 animation go on while its containing component is hidden?